# c++ class inheritance issue

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am having some troubles with c++ inheritance and I cannot find the error. I have  class that implements a simple unicycle kinematic model.

```
namespace kinematics{

class Unicycle{
    // state variables
    geometry_msgs::Pose2D _state;   ///< position of the robot

    // robot parameters
    float _max_linear_vel;          ///< maximum linear velocity, saturation
    float _b;                       ///< output point offset

    // integration variables
    float _int_step;                ///< integration step

protected:
    void _updateOdometry(float dv, float tr);
    void _ioLinearization(float vx, float vy, double &d, double &t);

public:
    Unicycle();
    Unicycle(float is, float b, float vmax, geometry_msgs::Pose2D initS);
};

}
```

Since a differential drive kinematic model is an extension to the unicycle I would like to implement using inheritance.

```
#include "unicycle/Unicycle.h"

class DiffDrive: public kinematics::Unicycle {
    //robot parameters
    float _wheel_radius;        ///< wheel radius
    float _wheel_separation;    ///< distance between wheels

    void _wheelSpeed(float dv, float tr, float &rs, float &ls);

public:
    DiffDrive();
    DiffDrive(float wr, float ws, geometry_msgs::Pose2D initS,
        float ts, float vmax, float b);
};
```

I wrote the constructor in this way

```
DiffDrive::DiffDrive(float wr,
                     float ws,
                     geometry_msgs::Pose2D initS,
                     float ts,
                     float vmax,
                     float b)
    :Unicycle(ts,b,vmax,initS), _wheel_radius{wr}, _wheel_separation{ws}{
}
```

However when I use the function _wheelSpeed()

```
void DiffDrive::_wheelSpeed(float dv, float tr, float &rs, float &ls){
    ls = dv - _wheel_separation*tr/2.f;
    ls = ls/_wheel_radius;

    rs = _wheel_separation*tr/_wheel_radius + ls;
    std::cout << "PARS: " << _wheel_separation << " - " << _wheel_radius << std::endl;

    std::cout << "WHEELS: " << rs << " - " << ls << std::endl;
}
```

The value of _wheel_separation and _wheel_radius are different from what expected:

> PARS: -179014 - 4.58631e-41

Even if the constructor is invoked with the following values:

```
wheel_radius = 0.02;
wheel_sep = 0.04;
_diff_drive = new DiffDrive(wheel_radius,wheel_sep,update_period,vel_max,offset);
```

Please help me understand what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Try to simplify the code to the bare essentials needed to reproduce the error. For example, remove the classes and leave just a function with a calculation. It is also not clear what you are expecting.

Comment: @MagoNick: _"a differential drive kinematic model is an extension to the unicycle"_ **but is it, though?** _"I would like to implement using inheritance"_ **yet there is no polymorphic behavior that the derived needs from the base.**

Comment: @JohannGerell: probably I said it wrong, what I am trying to do is to reuse the code of the unicycle to implement the differential drive. Probably 'inheritance' was not the right concept. Is it clear what I am trying to do?

Comment: Works for me, with minimal changes to make a compilable test case: http://ideone.com/ksRsAS. You're probably calling the function on an invalid object, but without seeing how it's called, I can't guess what's wrong. Please post a test case which demonstrates the problem (preferably with irrelevant code removed).

Comment: Do not use variables names beginning with underscore: it is considered a bad practice, since some compilers (e.g., old gcc versions) use those names for reserved variables.

Comment: I think you're calling your method on a object which was created through your default constructor (without parameters).

Comment: Off hand, it doesn't look as if `Unicycle` was designed to be used as a base class.  It's probably more appropriate to have a `Unicycle` member, rather than inherit from it (and if inheriting, it might be more appropriate to use private inheritance).

Comment: @Claudio: I did not know it,thanks for the advice. Ill try to find a document for the c++ naming good practice.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Am I missing something in Unicycle? However Unicycle is never called for the function _wheelSpeed that is what is confusing me

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, that's what I also alluded to with my comment - `Unicycle` and `DiffDrive` could both compose a third structure that is now part of `Unicycle`.

Comment: @JohannGerell: I see what you say. In the case I would like to implement it as inheritance, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the differences between inheritance and composition.
Think of it this way:
Is a differential drive a unicycle or is a differential drive a part of a unicycle?
Doesn't inheritance make more sense in this way:

- Cycle is a base class
- Unicycle is a derived class
- Tricycle is another derived class.

Differential drive is something that is a part of a unicycle.

I think if the design is correct, the rest will fall in place automatically.  The values you are getting look like either uninitialised values or values of an object that was already destroyed (again uninitialised values.)

Comment: Acutally a differential drive IS a unicycle. The difference is that requires some more computation to be driven. That is why I tried to use such design

Comment: And if I want to use the differential drive object in a car, does it make sense for it to inherit from a unicycle?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. I remember that in Java it was allowed to invoke a constructor from another constructor so to hide some parameters and avoid to rewrite the entire initialization. For example:

```
constructor1(par 1, par2){
  par3 = 0;
  constructor2(par1,par2,par3);
}
```

I am not sure that this is correct, but that is what I thought.
Therefore I implemented my constructor in the following way

```
DiffDrive::DiffDrive(const float wr,
                     const float ws,
                     float ts,
                     float vmax,
                     float b):Unicycle(ts,b,vmax){
    geometry_msgs::Pose2d initS;
    initS.x = 0;
    initS.y = 0;
    initS.theta = 0;

    DiffDrive(wr,ws,initS,ts,vmax,b);

}
```

Unfortunately this is not legal in C++, that returned the result of the instantiation of the outer constructor ignoring the inner one. 
I apologize if I didn't put this constructor in the previous question, but I simply forgot about it. I was my mistake.
thanks for the help and sorry for wasting your time.